# Classes and Member Variables

Tags: c++, class, visibility, private-members

Let's say I have a container class called `myList`.  This container class has a private member variable called `capacity` that holds the number of values in the instance.

It might be beneficial for users of the class to have access to `capacity` for, say, knowing when they've reached the end while going through each value in a loop.  Therefore, `capacity` should be public.

However, that would also allow users of the class to modify `capacity`, which would obviously screw things up.

```
myList myInstance;
myInstance.capacity = 123;
```

Would it be considered bad practice to have a public member function that just returns the value of `capacity`, which would be a private variable?  For example:

```
unsigned int getCapacity()
{
    return capacity;
}
```

What about a "clone" variable that's updated to the value of `capacity` whenever the value of `capacity` changes?  Users of the class would access the public "clone" rather than the private variable itself.

Comment: "It might be beneficial for users of the class to have access to capacity..." -- I doubt it's actually true. The use of `std::vector` demonstrated that exposing capacity is useless. On another note, getters (and setters) destroy encapsulation, they are almost as bad as public variables, so one must have a really good excuse when creating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a capacity getter.
But mark it as a const member:

```
unsigned int getCapacity()  const
{                        //^^^^^^^ 
    return capacity;
}
```

The second solution does not work.
As it is not reliable (one user may update it then the next user would get an invalid value when they read it).

Though you should consider if the user of your class really neads this information.
What can they do with it?

So you want to pre-allocate memeory if the capacity is not enough?

```
MyList   x;
// I am going to add 10 items make sure there is enough room.
if (x.size() + 10 < x.capacity())
{    x.resize(x.size() + 10);
}
```

In this situation just always re-size. Then make your container do nothing if it aleady has the space.

```
x.resize(x.size() + 10);  // If the container has enough space do nothing. 
                          // Otherwise make sure there is enough room for 10 more items.
```

It is usually better for an object to manage it's self, rather than provide access to its internal state to allow other objects to manage it indirectly. Even though you are de-coupling the implementation from the actual variable you are still coupling yourself to the interface of having a capacity and it does not really provide you with a meaningful benefit.

So methods should (generally) be actions (verbs) that perform actions on the object. These actions manipulate the state of the object. Let the actions be the interface to your object. Note that once you define the interface to an object changing that interface (removing functionality) is very hard.

Comment: @Maxpm: It informs the compiler that the method does not change the state of the object. const correctness is a big part of C++ and allows the compiler to stop you doing silly things by verifying that a method that does not change state does not accidentally call a method that does change the state.

Answer (score 2):

The accessor is a good solution. This is the one choosen by the STL. See std::vector::capacity(), std::vector::size(), ...

Answer (score 2):

The first solution you describe is known as a getter, and it is considered good practice to have these.

The second solution is not actually a solution, it merely adds a second variable and introduces the necessity to update it.

Answer (score 1):

No that would not be a bad practice.  In fact using getters and setters is considered a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

not a bad practice at all, thats how you need to do this actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public getter, you can just return a copy of, or const reference to capacity.

That will allow client's to see but not modify the data.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to expose implementation details.

Comment: @John Dibling - What 'implementation details' are you referring to?

Comment: The type of the `capacity` member variable.  If you return a const reference, you are exposing that this is an `unsigned` or whatever it may be.  If this changes in the future (to say an `unsigned long`) all client code will have to be recompiled.  Returning the value by-value instead does not expose implementation details.

Comment: @John Dibling - Unless I'm mistaken, If you return by value and increase the size of capacity, its still a binary break for existing clients so I don't see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: This is where abstract classes come in to play.  It's a question of degrees.  You can completely separate the interface from the implementation by using abstract classes & factory functions, but this impells more work on the library developer.  You can completely ignore seperation of interface from implementation, but this implies more work or longer/more frequent compiles for the library user.  Or you can take a middle approach, which strikes a balance between the two.  Three approaches for different scenarios, as there is not one approach that is appropriate for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you return the `private` member by value or a const pointer instead of its address through non-const pointer you will be fine.